# Diffraction Grating Formula

Tags: waves, diffraction

[image]

Consider the following diffraction grating formula, explained from my physics textbook. Here the angle is described as between $n=0$ and $n=1$. However, this is slightly confusing. Couldn't the angle be between $n=0$ and any other $n$ order of maxima? That is, not just restricted to be between $n=0$ and $n=1$. So what is the textbook trying to say here? Doesn't make sense to me.

[image]

Here the textbook says that $θ$ is the angle between $n=0$ and $n=1$ yet again. Couldn't the angle $θ$ be between $n=0$ and any other $n$ maxima? I don't think the textbook should be wrong, so what is it trying to state here?

Comment: The book is wrong. In the equation $d\sin\theta = n\lambda$ the angle $\theta$ is the angle between the zeroth and $n$th fringe.